# Jsoup iterate over Elements causes duplicated output

Tags: java, for-loop, jsoup, element

I have a page link to extract some data from it (I want to get  tables' some tds attributes).
[image: This image as a source sample]

I used for-loop to iteration via elements that I have to extract some attributes
of it . but I get duplicated output.

The output should be like the output at the image on the end of my post

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.saudisale.com/SS_a_mpg.aspx").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("table").select("tbody").select("tr").select("td") ;

for(Element e:elements) {
    System.out.println(e.select("span[id~=Label4]").text() + 
            "\t" + e.select("input[id$=ImageButton1]").attr("src") + 
            "\t" + "" + e.select("span[id~=Label13]").text());
}
```

This is the output that I get them, they are duplicated!!! :

[image]

```
The output should be like this:-
```

[image]

Comment: where is the duplicate? could you be more specific about this duplicate thing?

Comment: @Lrrr for example take this e.select("span[id~=Label4]").text(), all Elements are printed on the first line and then each Element duplicated two time at least at the output .

Comment: guess your top css query "table tbody tr td" is too general and returns some elements several times. You should select what you want only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used for-loop with incrementing counter instead and  problem  solved.
where 31 is the number of items on that page

The following code gives the desired output.

```
for(int i=1;i<description.size();i++)
{

System.out.println(elements.select("td").select("span[id~=Label4]").get(i).text()+""+elements.select("td").select("input[id$=ImageButton1]").get(i).attr("src"));   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try below code?

```
    Elements description = doc.select("tbody");
    doc=Jsoup.parse(description.html());
    description = doc.select("td");

    for(int j = 0; j < description.size(); ++ j)
    {
        String bodytext = description.eq(j).text(); // bodytext is the text of each TD
    }
```

Comment: An explanation of why this code works would be helpful

Comment: @mirzapinku this code works, but I dont't want text of each TD, I want to extract some attribute of some TD as specific manner vertically, my problem that my code duplicates the output